# Guillotine: Face up or visible?

Tags: guillotine

In Guillotine, the rules state that the cards should be "face up". But is it ok to stack the nobles on top of each other into piles? Technically, they are still face up, but the points are not visible. Or perhaps the point value should be visible at all times as to avoid confusion?

I guess the real question is, should other players be able to "count" your points at all times, or is it ok to make it harder for them to do so?

Comment: Unless firmly stated otherwise, "face up" does imply that the information should be easily accessible to all players. I don't see any reason you couldn't pile them all up in one nice little stack, but you do need to allow other players to look through your entire pile if they choose to do so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Page 9 of the [official rules](http://files.boardgamegeek.com/file/download/eycypntqg/Guillotine_english_rules_scan.PDF?) states that players are allowed to check your nobles to see how many points have been scored.

Answer (score 5):

In my personal opinion, "face up" is intended to mean "all information is visible to all players". Otherwise, you could also place them face up on the table but under a nontransparent cloth, which would give even less information than placing them face down.